# Pytorch error on multi-GPU setup: cannot import name 'invoke_remote_python_udf' from 'torch.distributed'

Tags: import, gpu, pytorch

I'm getting this below error when importing Pytorch.

"cannot import name 'invoke_remote_python_udf' from 'torch.distributed'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar problem. For me , the problem was occuring due to mismatch in `cuda` version. I am using `conda` environment.

In my system the `nvcc --version` showed the result as `10.0' , while I had mistakenly install the pytorch for cuda version`10.1`

I removed the `torch` and `torchvision` and re-installed them using the following command:

`conda install pytorch torchvision cuda100 -c pytorch`.

Installing the package `cuda100` solved the problem.